# Should `Phone` be a class or a struct in C#?

Tags: c#, class, struct

I have a `Phone` type with two properties: `Number` and `Description` (work, home, cell, etc.). I do not know if it should be a `class` or a `struct`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> **AVOID** defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (**int**, **double**, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

I am certain it will not be more than 16 bytes, but I am not sure it will meet the other requirements. So which should I use?

Comment: "It is immutable." You should use a class.

Comment: Personally, I'd just always default to picking `class`. If you then find yourself jumping through lots of hoops, then *consider* whether the type is actually a `struct`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Please put it in an answer

Comment: pretty good explanation already on SO: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/when-do-you-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class

Comment: At the first glance, it looks like `struct`, but `class` is more *flexible* than `struct`, so if you don't expect to have *performance* problems 
(you don't have millions of instances, you don't want microsecond response etc.) then start with `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, use a `class`. It works better in most cases anyway. `struct`s are for special cases - you'll know when you hit one.

Comment: That's the way of thinking I have ahah :)
Because IMO, it looks like a class design, and I am almost sure you'll be one day trapped by the copy constructor of the struct when passed as parameter ! So definitely, unless you know you want a struct, define your object as a Class !

Comment: I've often switched from a `struct` to a `class`, but never the other way round.